# Flutter Google Map create Card for each Markers, issue

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, google-maps-markers

**This is what i have:**
[image]

**And this is the want i want:**
[image]

**This is my code:**

```
const double ZOOM = 1;

class Location2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  @override
  _Location2 createState() => _Location2();
}

class _Location2 extends State<Location2> {
  static GoogleMapController? _googleMapController;
  Set<Marker> markers = Set();

  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controllerGoogleMap = Completer(); 
  late GoogleMapController newGoogleMapController;

  Directions? _info;

  List<LatLng> pointsNew = [];

  late LatLng latLng;
  late LatLng latLatPosition;
  late Position currentPosition;
  var geoLocator = Geolocator();
  double bottomPaddingOfMap = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {});
  }
  static const CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = const CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(40.7956, 29.4420),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  ); 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Location").snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          // ignore: avoid_print
          print(snapshot);
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            //Extract the location from document
            var locationList = snapshot.data!.docs.toList();
            //GeoPoint location = snapshot.data!.docs.first.get("location");

            List<GeoPoint> createLocationList = [];
            for (int i = 0; i < locationList.length; i++) {
              GeoPoint findLocation = locationList[i].get("location");

              createLocationList.add(findLocation);
            }

            // Check if location is valid
            // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
            if (createLocationList[0] == null) {
              return const Text("There was no location data");
            }

            // Remove any existing markers
            markers.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < createLocationList.length; i++) {
              //createLocationList

              latLng = LatLng(createLocationList[i].latitude,
                  createLocationList[i].longitude);

              String? title1 = locationList[i].get("title");
              String? snippet1 = locationList[i].get("snippet");

              markers.add(Marker(
                markerId: const MarkerId("location"),
                position: latLng,
                infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: title1, snippet: snippet1),
              ));
            }
            _googleMapController?.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
              CameraPosition(
                target: latLng,
                zoom: ZOOM,
              ),
            ));
            return Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                GoogleMap(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: bottomPaddingOfMap),
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                  markers: markers,
                  initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
                  myLocationEnabled: true,
                  zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                  zoomControlsEnabled: true,
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                    _controllerGoogleMap.complete(controller);
                    newGoogleMapController = controller;
```

**and this is the code (what i wanted) in the example image (codes are very old so doesn't work without changes):**

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool mapToggle = false;
  bool clientsToggle = false;
  bool resetToggle = false;

  var currentLocation;

  var clients = [];

  var currentClient;
  var currentBearing;

  GoogleMapController mapController;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Geolocator().getCurrentPosition().then((currloc) {
      setState(() {
        currentLocation = currloc;
        mapToggle = true;
        populateClients();
      });
    });
  }

  populateClients() {
    clients = [];
    Firestore.instance.collection('markers').getDocuments().then((docs) {
      if (docs.documents.isNotEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          clientsToggle = true;
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < docs.documents.length; ++i) {
          clients.add(docs.documents[i].data);
          initMarker(docs.documents[i].data);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  initMarker(client) {
    mapController.clearMarkers().then((val) {
      mapController.addMarker(MarkerOptions(
          position:
              LatLng(client['location'].latitude, client['location'].longitude),
          draggable: false,
          infoWindowText: InfoWindowText(client['clientName'], 'Nice')));
    });
  }

  Widget clientCard(client) {
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0, top: 10.0),
        child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                currentClient = client;
                currentBearing = 90.0;
              });
              zoomInMarker(client);
            },
            child: Material(
              elevation: 4.0,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              child: Container(
                  height: 100.0,
                  width: 125.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                      color: Colors.white),
                  child: Center(child: Text(client['clientName']))),
            )));
  }

  zoomInMarker(client) {
    mapController
        .animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(
                client['location'].latitude, client['location'].longitude),
            zoom: 17.0,
            bearing: 90.0,
            tilt: 45.0)))
        .then((val) {
      setState(() {
        resetToggle = true;
      });
    });
  }

  resetCamera() {
    mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
        CameraPosition(target: LatLng(40.7128, -74.0060), zoom: 10.0))).then((val) {
             setState(() {
                     resetToggle = false;
             });
        });
  }

  addBearing() {
    mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
      CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(currentClient['location'].latitude, 
        currentClient['location'].longitude
      ),
      bearing: currentBearing == 360.0 ? currentBearing : currentBearing + 90.0,
      zoom: 17.0,
      tilt: 45.0
    )
    )
    ).then((val) {
      setState(() {
        if(currentBearing == 360.0) {}
        else {
          currentBearing = currentBearing + 90.0;
        }
      });
    });
      }

      removeBearing() {
    mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
      CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(currentClient['location'].latitude, 
        currentClient['location'].longitude
      ),
      bearing: currentBearing == 0.0 ? currentBearing : currentBearing - 90.0,
      zoom: 17.0,
      tilt: 45.0
    )
    )
    ).then((val) {
      setState(() {
        if(currentBearing == 0.0) {}
        else {
          currentBearing = currentBearing - 90.0;
        }
      });
    });
      }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Map Demo'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 80.0,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: mapToggle
                        ? GoogleMap(
                            onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
                            options: GoogleMapOptions(
                                cameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                                    target: LatLng(40.7128, -74.0060),
                                    zoom: 10.0)),
                          )
                        : Center(
                            child: Text(
                            'Loading.. Please wait..',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                          ))),
                Positioned(
                    top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 250.0,
                    left: 10.0,
                    child: Container(
                        height: 125.0,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: clientsToggle
                            ? ListView(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                children: clients.map((element) {
                                  return clientCard(element);
                                }).toList(),
                              )
                            : Container(height: 1.0, width: 1.0))),
                resetToggle
                    ? Positioned(
                        top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                            (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                            50.0),
                        right: 15.0,
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                          onPressed: resetCamera,
                          mini: true,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                        ))
                    : Container(),
                resetToggle
                    ? Positioned(
                        top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                            (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                            50.0),
                        right: 60.0,
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                          onPressed: addBearing,
                          mini: true,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                          child: Icon(Icons.rotate_left
                        ))
                    )
                    : Container(),
                resetToggle
                    ? Positioned(
                        top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                            (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                            50.0),
                        right: 110.0,
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                          onPressed: removeBearing,
                          mini: true,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                          child: Icon(Icons.rotate_right)
                        ))
                    : Container()
              ],
            )
          ],
        ));
  }

  void onMapCreated(controller) {
    setState(() {
      mapController = controller;
```

Here is the relative video (he used firestore): [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hg8CT3ysFjY&t=1040s)
And this is the relative video (he didn't use firestore, all datas from models: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CjhXyY_92xU)
**How can I code it to my app as in these examples?**